# Extract comment data except one in xslt

Tags: xslt

Input xml is like that,

```
<section level="2" counter="yes">
<title id="c1_3"><!--1.3--> Reeve’s Prosthesis (1972)</title>
<figure counter="yes" id="f1_1">
<legend><para><!--<emph type="bold">Fig. 1.1</emph>--> Reeve’s prosthesis. (Reproduced with permission from Reeves B, Jobbins B, Dowson D, Wright V. A Total Shoulder Endo-Prosthesis. Eng Med 1972;1(3):64–67.)</para></legend>
<para><!--<inline-figure xlink:href="images/copy.jpg"/>--></para>
</figure>
</section>
```

Output should be,

```
<section level="2" counter="yes">
<title id="c1_3">1.3 Reeve’s Prosthesis (1972)</title>
<figure counter="yes" id="f1_1">
<legend><para><emph type="bold">Fig. 1.1</emph> Reeve’s prosthesis. (Reproduced with permission from Reeves B, Jobbins B, Dowson D, Wright V. A Total Shoulder Endo-Prosthesis. Eng Med 1972;1(3):64–67.)</para></legend>
<para><!--<inline-figure xlink:href="images/copy.jpg"/>--></para>
</figure>
</section>
```

My xslt wrote like this,

```
<xsl:template match="document//comment()">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="ancestor::para | ancestor::caption | ancestor::section | ancestor::document">
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;comment&gt;</xsl:text>
<xsl:variable name="commentText0"><xsl:copy-of select="replace(normalize-space(.),' ',' ')"/></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="commentText2"><xsl:value-of select="replace($commentText0, 'Fig([.]) ', 'Fig. ')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="commentText3"><xsl:value-of select="replace($commentText2, 'Table ', 'Table ')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="replace($commentText3, 'Formula ', 'Formula ')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/comment&gt;</xsl:text>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="comment[contains(.,'inline-figure')]">
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!--</xsl:text>                
<xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>                
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">--&gt;</xsl:text>
</xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

I want to extract comment content except `<inline-figure>` element. Could you please guide me that how to write code for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot of stuff in your XSLT that seems to bear no relationship to your stated requirement. Assuming you have an XSLT environment where disable-output-escaping is working, you should be able to simply do:

```
<xsl:template match="comment()">
  <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="comment()[contains(., 'inline-figure')]">
  <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>
```

I can't see what the rest of your logic is trying to achieve.

Note also that disable-output-escaping generally works only when writing final serialized output from the transformation, not when writing to a variable.

Comment: Thanku for your response Michael. It's giving parser error as shown below.
Severity: warning
Description: XTRE0540: Ambiguous rule match for /comment()[1] Matches both "comment()" on line 101 of file:/D:/XSLT/2.1to3.0/sample/kis_2.1to3.0.xsl and "node()" on line 8 of file:/D:/XSLT/2.1to3.0/sample/kis_2.1to3.0.xsl

Severity: warning
Description: XTRE0540: Ambiguous rule match for /document/part[2]/title[1]/comment()[1] Matches both "comment()" on line 101 of file:/D:/XSLT/2.1to3.0/sample/kis_2.1to3.0.xsl and "node()" on line 8 of file:/D:/XSLT/2.1to3.0/sample/kis_2.1to3.0.xsl

Comment: xpath is repeating twice which does not required.

Comment: If you have ambiguous template rules, use the `priority` attribute to say which takes precedence.

Answer (score 0):

Asuming XSLT 3.0 (as supported by Saxon 9.8 or Altova 2017/2018) you could use

```
<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

<xsl:template match="document//comment()[not(contains(., 'inline-figure'))]">
   <xsl:copy-of select="parse-xml-fragment(.)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Well, I did clearly say that it is XSLT 3.0 and I only did that as `parse-xml-fragment` is available in XSLT 3.0/XPath 3.0/3.1. So you will need to move to Saxon 9.8 or current versions of Altova to use the above.

Comment: Thank u for your response Martin. But, we require the code in XSLT 2.0 since we are using Oxygen XML editor V 15.0. In that parser is available till Saxon-9.5.0.2